# Fitness tracking using Python Numpy and Matplotlib module. Takes latest data from a specified folder and stores them in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I have a folder fitness_tracker, where i have more folders like Location GPS 2021-10-23. the only difference between folders is the date. IN all these subfolders there is a CSV file Named Raw Data.
Raw Data includes, time velocity latitude longitiude in different columns. i want to write a program that goes into fitness_tracker, takes the latest folders ( lets say 5 out of 10 folders ) by reading the file names and goes into those folders and reads the Raw Data csv files and stores time data in a single matrix array. right now i can do it for a single file using NUMPY.

i want to read time value from Raw Data from separate folder and store it in a matrix
`time = np.array([t1, t2, t3,t4,t5])`
and then use these data to make a graph using matplot lib

this is the program i am running now.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
bus_data = np.loadtxt('Raw Data.csv',delimiter=',',skiprows=1)  # 1a. Import GPS File
time = bus_data[:,0]/60     # Second to minute
latitude = bus_data[:,1]
longitude = bus_data[:,2]
altitude = bus_data[:,3]    # Unit = Meter
speed = bus_data[:,5]       # Unit = Meter / second
distance = bus_data[:,7]    # Unit = kilometer

fig1, axs1 = plt.subplots(1, 1)
axs1.plot(distance, speed, 'k.',markersize = 1, label='data')
axs1.set(xlabel='Distance (km)', ylabel='Speed (m/s)')
axs1.set_title('Speed over Distance')
axs1.legend()
plt.savefig('Speed over Distance.png',dpi=200)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I'd get the time data from a List of directories:

```
import numpy as np
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

directories = [dir1, dir2, ...]

files = []
for directory in directories:
    files.append([f for f in listdir(directory) if isfile(join(directory, f)) and f.endswith(".csv")])

data = []
for file in files:
    data.append(np.loadtxt('Raw Data.csv',delimiter=',',skiprows=1))
    
time = []
for d in data:
    time.append(d[:,0]/60)
```

If you want to get the list of directories based on their name (and thus their date) you'll have to do some more work parsing dates from the names of the folders, but i guess that deserves a new question, as this one is already asked way too broadly imho.

Comment: Hi thanks for the feedback. I tried your code, but it reads the CSV file from the program directory instead of the directory i have provided.

Comment: I just tried it and it works fine. How did you provide the directories?

Comment: Hi . Sorry. it worked fine. i dont know whats wrong with python. My first attempt failed . but today i tried it again and it works. Maybe i did something wrong the first time.